# Display port Audio Pass through Issue

Tags: sound, radeon, displayport

I recently switched an old machine over to **Ubuntu 19.10**. My main problem is that display port audio pass through is not working consistently.

**Primary Symptom:** I will often receive no sound.  The sound panel in settings shows that audio is playing (level meter under output device shows activity).  However, no sound actually plays over the speakers.

**Partial Fix:** Fiddling with things that may reinitialize the display connection - mostly <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f1</kbd> and then log back in will sometimes resolve the issue.  Once audio is playing, the current source will continue working, but other sources like even as simple as opening a different website, may not work.Some days even repeated efforts to do this, switch audio device in settings and switch back, etc. will not get it working. But it will work the next day.

**Setup:** **Ubuntu 19.10** and **ASUS Radeon 390**.  390 defaults to the Radeon driver, so I'm on that driver.  Monitor is an **MG279Q** and is the only monitor connected.  I set display port **1.1** on the monitor end because **1.2** and especially refresh rates over **60hz** caused all sorts of display (video) issues.

**Potential Cause:** I believe it's related to a display port training issue. This seems consistent with it occasionally starting to work after doing things that may retrain the display connection. **Dmesg** shows the following:

```
 - [   32.313641] rfkill: input handler enabled
 - [   32.483102] radeon_dp_aux_transfer_native: 830 callbacks suppressed
 - [   32.806386] [drm:radeon_dp_link_train [radeon]] *ERROR* channel eq failed: 5 tries
 - [   32.806400] [drm:radeon_dp_link_train [radeon]] *ERROR* channel eq failed
 - [   32.916544] [drm:radeon_dp_link_train [radeon]] *ERROR* channel eq failed: 5 tries
 - [   32.916559] [drm:radeon_dp_link_train [radeon]] *ERROR* channel eq failed
 - [   34.763442] rfkill: input handler disabled
```

**Fixes Tried:**

- I added "**options radeon audio=1**" to `/etc/modprobe.d/radeon.conf`, which was suggested for older versions of Ubuntu.  This did not have an impact.
- Running **speaker-test** (e.g. `speaker-test --channel 2 --rate 48000 -d hw:0,1`) or the speaker test in settings does not play any sound even when the audio is working. I found this command listed as a potential fix for **hdmi** audio pass through.

**Secondary Issue:** The fans on my GPU are not being correctly managed.  The system leaves the fans at low speed as the GPU basically slowly overheats. I mention it as I do not know if this is in any way related to my main driver issue.

My current workaround for this is to run **pwmconfig** to unlock the fans (and set to max speed). **Pwmconfig** itself fails immediately with a message about no working fan sensors. Once the fan control is unlocked, I overwrite `/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon#/pwm1` to **128** to slow the fans to a reasonable speed.

**Driver:** I've not tried changing driver.

- The Ubuntu version of **amdgpu** does not list the 390 as a supported model.  It's also unclear to me whether the Ubuntu version of **amdgpu** supports display port pass through audio. The help page explicitly says it does not support HDMI audio pass through but makes no mention of display port pass through.
- The AMD distributed version of **amdgpu-pro** does list the 390 as supported but only supports **18.04 LTS**.

**Other:**

- Hardware is all fine.  No issues on **Windows 10**.
- I can no longer access the community help pages. When I restarted and restored my Firefox session, the reload of 3 help pages triggered surge protection. I've been locked out for over **an hour**. This seems generally ridiculous, but know I won't be able to read any linked page there.

Any thoughts on how to resolve?  Has anyone experienced and resolved similar issues?